# 64 bit Ubuntu on intel x86_64

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, intel, amd-processor

I know that my question is certanly duplicate, but I've spent a whole morning on trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 amd64 on my laptop (intel pentium quad core n3540, 4 GB RAM) and have failed, even though I've been reading that it is possible to install 64bit ubuntu on intel pc.

My question is, can someone please, explain to me HOW (the devil is in the details, so dont be cheap with it) to do it?

When I try it, my laptop freezes, on the initial load, so I cant even make it to the menu.
I dont know what am I doing wrong, so please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

Secure boot was enabled in BIOS. Disabled it and made it without any problems

Answer (score 0):

Intel quad core is definitely amd64 processor, so 64 bit is correct arch. However you may try to run i386 arch (it will see full RAM). Only difference it available software (and in fact i386 have more software than amd64, so for 64bit processors I advice to use multi arch so you have both architectures).

If i386 won't work you may try with old version and once you find working one then make full update to latest version. It worked for my friend on old PC.

There is one more problem. Try to run system without GUI. Problem with graphics card driver may cause similar problems (accidentally checked it once).

Comment: Thank you my friend, I saw your answer a few days ago, but didn't have time to respond. I already did a dual boot, installed win 10 64bit and Ubuntu 32bit, because I just didnt make it to install 64bit Ubuntu.

But, when I installed windows, it required me to change my BIOS boot settings, changing UEFI to Legacy.
Is it possible that Ubuntu 64bit required it too, but I just missed it?

Thank you for your response :)